# How to use an array which was initialized in the constructor in a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, constructor

I'm trying to define an array of a user defined number of elements (degrees) and then a method which allows the user to set an element (coefficient) one at a time.

```
class Polynomial 
{

    public Polynomial(int degree)
    {
        double[] coef = new double[degree];
    }

    public double[] setCoefficient(int index, double value) 
    {
        coef[index] = value; //coef was set in the constructor
        return coef;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error in `coef[index] = value;`.

Comment: read this link to understand variable scopes in java. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Comment: Simple: don't use a variable, but a **field**. This is really super basic stuff. Although you got a nice answer - please understand that this site is not about again and again explaining the same basics. Don't assume SO is a **replacement** for you reading books / following tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You defined the `coef` array as a local variable of your constructor, which means it cannot be used anywhere else.

You have to define it as an instance member in order to access it from other methods:

```
class Polynomial {

    private double[] coef; // declare the array as an instance member

    public Polynomial(int degree) 
    {
        coef = new double[degree]; // initialize the array in the constructor
    }

    public double[] setCoefficient(int index, double value) 
    {
        coef[index] = value; // access the array from any instance method of the class 
        return coef;
    }

}
```

Note that returning the member variable `coef` in `setCoefficient` would allow the user of this class to mutate the array directly (without having to call the `setCoefficient` method again), which is not a good idea. Member variables should be private and should only be mutated by methods of the class that contains them.

Therefore I'd change the method to:

```
public void setCoefficient(int index, double value) 
{
    // you should consider adding a range check here if you want to throw
    // your own custom exception when the provided index is out of bounds
    coef[index] = value;    
}
```

If you need access to elements of the array from outside the class, either add a `double getCoefficient(int index)` method that returns an individual value of the array, or add a `double[] getCoefficients()` method that would return **a copy** of the array.

Comment: I'm not sure why `setCoefficient` should return the field. Might be worth mentioning that.

Comment: Nice. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

this is a scope issue...

```
public Polynomial(int degree){
     double[] coef = new double[degree];
}
```

because **coef** cease to be accessible as soon as the constructor returns, so no method can get that object never...

Do instead:

```
class Polynomial {
    private double[] coef;

    public Polynomial(int degree) {
        coef = new double[degree];
    }
```

Comment: Correct answer, but basically duplicates Eran's.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re am almost always 20 seconds behind him.... :-)

Comment: so 20 seconds can be in SO a gap of 175K in the reputation....

Comment: haha, I know :) Just thought there is no need for two (kind of) exactly same answers. Nothing wrong with the answer though.

Comment: The really kewl thing would have been to close out the question as duplicate ;-)

Comment: 8 Punkte weg! naja :)